# @ symbol in Email field is causing problem at runtime in MVC3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3

The email textbox is getting filled by ä valid email id (say patra.bikash@gmail.com) from database at run time.
Thus I am getting run time JS error (Dynamic file) that gmail is not defined. (in MVC 3.0)
Any idea how to solve this?

If it would ve compile time, then I could have double prefixed with @ to avoid this problem, but how can I tackle it at runtime?
In the below code  @contacts.EmailAddress is fetching patra.bikash@gmail.com from my ViewModel.

```
<tbody id="BillingContactRows">
  @{
      if (Model.ContactList != null && Model.ContactList.Count > 0)
      {
         foreach (Models.Contact contacts in Model.ContactList)
         {
      <tr>
         <td>
               @if (contacts.Primary)
               {
                  <input type="radio" id="rdo.@contacts.ContactID" value="radio" checked="checked" name="contact" onclick=" SelectContact('@contacts.ContactID');" />
               }
               else
               {
                  <input type="radio" id="rdo.@contacts.ContactID" value="radio" name="contact" onclick=" SelectContact('@contacts.ContactID');" />
               }
         </td>
         <td>
               @contacts.ContactName
         </td>
         <td>
               @contacts.EmailAddress
         </td>
         <td>
               <span class="datatype3">
                  @contacts.Status
               </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
         }
      }
   }
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you post code, specifically where this error is occurring?

Comment: Can I see some code? How are you populating the textbox?

Comment: We want code! "Gmail not defined?" Is that the string value or the name of the field? :P

Comment: Added code snippet. Plz help.

Comment: Would it be possible to see the javascript where the error is occurring? Is it in the SelectContact() function?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name);

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

This means, in short, that you can't use the @ symbol for the id of the radio buttons.

I suggest that you create a helper method that you can call to translate the @ symbol to another - perhaps underscore - symbol

Comment: I should point out that the problem is not with the razor engine being confused by the inserted @ symbol, as perhaps you are thinking.  It is an unrelated problem, with Javascript not liking the @ symbol being used in your ID parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't razor render the value of `contacts.ContactID` instead of the `@` in the `id` attribute anyway?